# ПСП (правильная скобочня последовательность с выводом индекса) задача java

Tags: java

не могу решить задачку, из-за необходимости вывода неправильной скобки...нашел кучу вариантов где просто вывести правильная или нет,а здесь с выводом индекса неправильной скобки...

Ограничение времени 6 секунд
Ограничение памяти  64Mb
Ввод input.txt
Вывод стандартный вывод или output.txt

Василиса недавно узнала про «правильные скобочные последовательности» — последовательности из «(» и «)» такие, что существует хотя бы одно разбиение всех скобок последовательности на пары «(» и «)», для которых верно:
в любой паре порядковый номер «(» в последовательности меньше, чем у соответствующей ей «)».
каждая скобка относится ровно к одной паре из разбиения.
Например, последовательность «(()())()» правильная, так как существует разбиение (1,6), (2,3), (4,5), (7,8) (скобки нумеруются с 1 слева направо).

Примеры неправильных скобочных последовательностей:

«((()» неправильная, так как в единственно возможном разбиении (1,4), (2,4), (3,4) скобка 4 используется во всех трёх парах.
«)(» неправильная, так как в единственно возможном разбиении (2,1) позиция скобки «(» больше, чем позиция «)».
«((» неправильная, так как невозможно построить ни одной пары без скобок «)».

Василисе очень понравилась данная тематика, поэтому ей захотелось привнести туда чего-то нового и необычного. Поэтому Василиса придумала «почти правильную скобочную последовательность» — скобочную последовательность, из которой можно получить правильную скобочную последовательность удалением ровно одной скобки.

К примеру, последовательность «(()» является почти правильной, так как удаление любой скобки «(» приведет к правильной последовательности «()».

Последовательность «)» тоже является почти правильной, так как удаление единственной скобки приведет к пустой последовательности скобок, которая является правильной по определению.

У Василисы есть файлы с её решениями домашних заданий по математике. Она решила для каждого задания выяснить, является ли последовательность скобок в этих выражениях почти правильной — и, если это так, то найти наименьшую позицию скобки, после удаления которой последовательность скобок станет правильной.

Обратите внимание, что Василису не интересует корректность получающегося после удаления скобки выражения — она всецело сосредоточена только на корректности скобочной последовательности.

Формат ввода

В единственной строке файла содержится строка S (1≤∣∣S∣∣≤5⋅107) — решение одного из заданий по математике. Строка гарантированно завершается символом перевода строки.
Гарантируется, что строка S содержит символы только из указанных ниже:
строчные английские буквы `a - z`;
знаки математических операций: +, −, ∗, ∕, =;
скобки ( и );
пробел.

Формат вывода

Если последовательность скобок в решении является почти правильной, то выведите наименьшую позицию символа в строке, удаление которого сделает последовательность скобок правильной. В ином случае выведите число −1.
я решал во так,но это неправильно... и затратно по памяти

```
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("src/main/java/task5/input.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileReader);
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                str.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            System.out.println(str);
            scanner.close();
            task(str);
        }
    public static void task(StringBuilder str) {
        int o1 = 0;
        int z1 = 0;
        int o2 = 0;
        int z2 = 0;
        int flag = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> listO1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> listO2 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> listz1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> listz2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == '=') {
                flag = 1;
            }
            if (str.charAt(i) == '(' && flag == 0) {
                o1++;
                listO1.add(i + 1);
            }
            if (str.charAt(i) == ')' && flag == 0) {
                z1++;
                listz1.add(i + 1);
            }
            if (str.charAt(i) == '(' && flag == 1) {
                o2++;
                listO2.add(i + 1);
            }
            if (str.charAt(i) == ')' && flag == 1) {
                z2++;
                listz2.add(i + 1);
            }
        }

        if (o1 - z1 == 1 && o2 == z2) {
            System.out.println(listO1.get(0));
        } else if (o2 - z2 == 1 && o1 == z1) {
            System.out.println(listO2.get(0));
        } else if (o1 - z1 == -1 && o2 == z2) {
            System.out.println(listz1.get(0));
        } else if (o2 - z2 == -1 && o1 == z1) {
            System.out.println(listz2.get(0));
        } else {
            System.out.println(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: пример теста:
d + (a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c + d
вывод:
5

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос словесное описание вашего решения.

Comment: Сосчитав скобки можно узнать скобку какого типа надо удалить. И если это скобка одного типа, то удалить самую левую,  а если другого, то удалить ту что останется в стеке. :) (Стек не нужен, но так короче объяснять).

Comment: так и построен мое решение, но оно неправильное... элементарный тест не пройдет : ()(()=() в этом случае он укажет удалить 1 скобку,а надо 3

Comment: В стеке останется  скобка на третьем месте.

Comment: я вроде понимаю это,но не понимаю как реализовать это в коде)

Comment: Зачем в вашем решении особо обрабатывается символ `=`?

Comment: это в соответствии с условием задачи, чтобы выражение не поменялось, например тест () = ((), чтобы убрал именно в правой половине скобку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Специальная обработка для знака `'='` не нужна - в условии задачи сказано

> Обратите внимание, что Василису не интересует корректность
> получающегося после удаления скобки выражения — она всецело
> сосредоточена только на корректности скобочной последовательности.

Чтобы проверить что последовательность почти правильная считаем баланс скобок.

1. Если открывающих на одну больше чем закрывающих, то удалять надо самую правую открывающую скобку когда баланс нулевой (если попытаться удалить открывающую скобку левее, то в этом месте баланс будет -1, чего не может быть в правильной последовательности).
2. Если закрывающих скобок на одну больше чем открывающих, то удалять надо самую левую закрывающую (закрывающие скобки можно удалять любые, от этого баланс только возрастёт).
3. В иных случаях последовательность точно не почти правильная.

После удаления "плохой" скобки надо проверить что последовательность стала правильной. Предыдущие тесты иногда слишком оптимистичны.

```
public class Temp {

    private static boolean balanceIsOK(String expr, int ignore) {
        int depth = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < expr.length(); ++i) {
            if (i == ignore) {
                continue;
            }
            switch (expr.charAt(i)) {
            case '(':
                ++depth;
                break;
            case ')':
                if (depth == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                --depth;
                break;
            }
        }
        return depth == 0;
    }

    private static int findSuspiciousParen(String expr) {
        int depth = 0;
        int first_closing = -1;
        int last_opening_at_zero_depth = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < expr.length(); ++i) {
            switch (expr.charAt(i)) {
            case '(':
                if (depth == 0) {
                    last_opening_at_zero_depth = i;
                }
                ++depth;
                break;
            case ')':
                if (first_closing == -1) {
                    first_closing = i;
                }
                --depth;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (depth == 1) {
            return last_opening_at_zero_depth;
        }
        if (depth == -1) {
            return first_closing;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static int findWrongParen(String expr) {
        int ignore = findSuspiciousParen(expr);
        if (ignore != -1 && balanceIsOK(expr, ignore)) {
            return ignore + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        for (String expr : new String[] {
            "",
            "(",
            ")",
            "((",
            "(()",
            "()",
            "(()())()",
            "((()",
            ")(",
            "d + (a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c + d",
            "()(()=()",
            "() = (()"
        }) {
            System.out.println(findWrongParen(expr) + " " + expr);
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac Temp.java && java Temp 
> -1 
> 1 (
> 1 )
> -1 ((
> 1 (()
> -1 ()
> -1 (()())()
> -1 ((()
> -1 )(
> 5 d + (a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c + d
> 3 ()(()=()
> 6 () = (()
> ```

Comment: спасибо большое!